# Get span and match values from SRE_Match objects(Python)

Tags: python, regex, object, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I am trying to find a match of certain length (range 4 to 12) in a DNA sequence

Below is the code:

```
import re
positions =[]
for i in range(4,12):
    for j in range(len(dna)- i+1):
        positions.append(re.search(dna[j:j+i],comp_dna))

#Remove the 'None' from the search
position_hits = [x for x in positions if x is not None]
```

I get this:

```
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='ATGC'>,.........]
```

How do I extract the value from span and match?
I have tried .group() but it throws out an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: What is your `DNA` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fix the current approach, you may use

```
position_hits = [x.group() for x in positions if x]
```

You may get all the matches directly in the `for` loop:

```
import re
position_hits = []
for i in range(4,12):
    for j in range(len(dna)-i+1):
        m = re.search(dna[j:j+i],comp_dna)
        position_hits.append(m.group())
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, but I will get the match values but I also need the span values. Is there a way to get the span values as well? Thanks

Comment: @Kian Perhaps, you are asking about [`position_hits.append(m.span())`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.span).